How to change text in input area
I’m trying to make a temperature converter. Right now I’ve started at getting from Celsius to Fahrenheit. My conversion function works correctly what doesn’t is putting Fahrenheit value of the Celsius degree into the Fahrenheit area right now it just enters NaN.
This is what I currently have
    let convert = document.getElementById(“convert”)
    convert.addEventListener(“click”,function(){
        let cel = document.getElementById(“cel”)
        let newTemp = convertCtoF(parseFloat(cel));
        document.getElementById(“fah”).value=newTemp;
   }


I believe you are missing .value. Without it, you are putting the entire DOM object into cel. Using .value will extract just the text from that object.
(I renamed the variables in the example for clarity, but they can be anything you like)
  let convert = document.getElementById("convert")

  convert.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let tempC = document.getElementById("cel").value
    let tempF = convertCtoF(parseFloat(tempC))
    document.getElementById("fah").value=tempF;
   }

